# Delete row from an sqlite database through file name and without knowing specific column

Tags: android, sqlite

is there a form of query which i can delete an entry from an sqlite database by just its file name without knowing the exact column it resides on.

i know this code could work, but i don't know what to put for my Where clause. i tried this but i don't know if am correct. Thank you.

```
  public boolean deleteTag(String entry ){
  return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{entry}) >0;      
    }
```

or is there anyway, i can retrieve the column name from querying a cursor.sorry  i know what am asking sounds strange. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

'Cursor.getColumnNames()`will give you array of names. Then you can loop through it and get column id by doing`Cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName)` is that what you are asking?

Comment: @Droidln.net sorry for the late response. not exactly what i am asking. i meant i am trying to delete a row that contains a particular filename, but i don't know the correct column which the filename resides on. so am looking for how to structure a query which will enable me delete the row with that filename without knowing the column or a query that will give me the exact column the filename resides. hope am clearer now.